Hydration is not happening in next js with zustand
We are having a nextjs(14) app router application with zustand state management. During SSR, we are prefilling the form data for the page. On client side we have some events based on change of one of the dropdown field. But user is changing the dropdown value before the hydration(mostly happening in slow networks) which doesnt trigger any event handlers as hydration didnt complete. We are expecting that after hydration is done, page should again be in the state that it is rendered during SSR changing dropdown value to default irrespective of user changes before hydration. But it is not happening.
Its working fine if we set the value in useEffect but we have many components where this need to be done.
Am I missing anything.

You're encountering a common issue in Next.js with Zustand where the client-side state doesn't sync properly with the server-rendered state if a user interacts with the page before hydration completes, especially in slow networks.
Potential Solutions
1. Force State Sync After Hydration
Use a useEffect to re-sync Zustand's state with the server-rendered state after hydration.
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useStore } from '../store';

useEffect(() => {
  const setDropdownValue = useStore((state) => state.setDropdownValue);
  const dropdownValue = useStore((state) => state.dropdownValue);
  setDropdownValue(dropdownValue);
}, []);

2. Use useSyncExternalStore
Leverage React 18's useSyncExternalStore to ensure consistent state between SSR and CSR.
import create from 'zustand';
import { subscribeWithSelector } from 'zustand/middleware';

const useStore = create(
  subscribeWithSelector((set) => ({
    dropdownValue: '',
    setDropdownValue: (value) => set({ dropdownValue: value }),
  }))
);

export const useHydratedStore = (selector) => {
  return useSyncExternalStore(
    useStore.subscribe,
    () => selector(useStore.getState()),
    () => selector(useStore.getState())
  );
};

3. Debounce User Interaction
Prevent or debounce user interactions until hydration completes.
const handleDropdownChange = useCallback((event) => {
  if (!hydrated) return; // Prevent interaction until hydration
  // Handle change
}, [hydrated]);

Choose the approach that best fits your application's needs.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
